# Pm2 watch ignore does not ignore file/image upload

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, multer, pm2

I want to upload an image using node(11.10.1),pm2(3.4.0),through Ubuntu 16.04. Like many others who have tried, I can receive an image from starting my server through node process but once I use PM2 to upload an image, PM2 restarts the server and there is no image uploaded.

I made a ecosystem and set different types of settings around like , watch, ignore, autoreset, cwd. I also tried the cli line of code where it is "sudo pm2 start server.js --ignore-watch "/public/images". I am not sure how I can ignore Pm2 the right way. I also made sure that i do have a file path at Myapp/public/images/

I have tried the following: 
[Multer upload files with PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690479/multer-upload-files-with-pm2)
[Expressjs pm2 ignore watch public/images folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070869/expressjs-pm2-ignore-watch-public-images-folder)
https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

my file structure:

```
    >MyApp 
       >ecosystem.config.js 
       >server.js  
       >public 
          >images
       >routes
```

this is my ecosystem

```
  'apps' : [{
    'name': 'pm2_checking_server',
    'script': 'server.js',
    'cwd': '/var/www/MyApp/'//........also tried it without cwd
    'watch': ['server.js'], //...........I also did true/false
    'ignore_watch': ['public/images/'],//...did variations like ./public/images, public/images... etc
    'watch_options': {
     'followSymlinks': false
    }
}],
```

this is my multer destination in MyApp/routes/

```
destination: function (req, files, cb) {

      cb(null, path.join(__dirname , '../public/images'))
}
```

I expect Pm2 to ignore the watching file upload but the response back I get from uploading an Image is "errno": -13,
        "code": "EACCES",
        "syscall": "open",
"path": "/var/www/MyApp/public/images/7ylxlncRKJ

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the difference with official examples is you are using single quote `'` and they have used double quote `"` after all this is a `json` file. Also you have missing a `,` at line:

```
"cwd": "/var/www/MyApp/",
```

Delete trailing `/` at: `public/images/`

So this is your `process.json` file which should be at root of your project:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "pm2_checking_server",
        "script": "server.js",
        "cwd": "/var/www/MyApp/",
        "watch": ["server.js"],
        "ignore_watch": ["public/images"],
        "watch_options": {
            "followSymlinks": false
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response
I added the double quotes and sorry for removing the comma there, I wanted to add comments there and accidentally removed it. I still have the same problem. 
 module.exports = {
  "apps" : [{
    "name": "pm2_checking_server",
    "script": "server.js",
    "cwd": "/var/www/MyApp/",
    "watch": ["server.js"],
    "ignore_watch": ["public/images/"],
    "watch_options": {
    "followSymlinks": false
    }
}],
};

Comment: Paste your config in an online [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/) and check its validity. I'm pretty sure something is wrong with your config. Actually this is the only thing that cause problem you have at hand.

Comment: I just validated and changed it around( I had to remove the comma after the app[array] and change some white spaces around). I still cannot upload an image. I am also using "sudo pm2 start ecosystem.config.js" at /var/www/MyApp for your reference as well.

Comment: @ebbandflows: `ecosystem.config.js` ?! You are using the json version of config file and it should be `ecosystem.json`.

Comment: I had the js version because of https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/ said to do a pm2 init. I also tried to make it into a json file, but I still have the same result when i upload.

Comment: I have the changed JSON code you posted as well as different variations on it which gave me the same result. I ran it from /var/www/MyApp where I used sudo pm2 and started ecosystem.json. I saw that there is a post on https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2629 where this issue is remaining? Also, thank you for your help i really appreciate it!